# Where can I find the "Create Computer Object" Permission in Windows Server 2016?

Tags: active-directory, permissions, windows-server-2016, failovercluster, windows-cluster

I'm trying to prestage the cluster name object for the cluster I'm creating. I'm looking at the steps provided here (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc731002(v=ws.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#to-prestage-a-cluster-name-account) but there's no "Create Computer Object" permission in the Permission Entry window (Active Directory Users and Computers > CNO > Properties > Security > Advanced > Add)

[These are all the permissions listed in the window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZCLiD.png)

I'm just wondering, has this been renamed to a completely different permission in Windows Server 2016?

I've used the local and domain administrator accounts and still can't find the said permission.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: From the way you've written the question, it sounds like you're editing the permissions on the CNO?  You're supposed to be editing the permissions on the Computers folder, as per step 8.

Answer (score 1):

The "Create Computer Object" permission is granted on the folder/OU your object gets created in, usually and per default the "Computers" OU in your domain view.